# Assembly Program Issues

Tags: assembly, recursion, calculator

Im trying to write a program in assembly that will act as a Compound interest counter that uses a recursive loop. I was able to get the program working with a set Principal and set interest rate and it iterated 10 times, showing the balance after each iteration. Now I'm trying to **change it** so it asks the user for a starting principal, an interest rate, and target principal. The program then needs to iterate until the target principal is met.

This is my non-working code so far. I think im messing up with which registers I'm using. Iv tried changing this registers being used on the beq lines to $a2 and $a0  but that didnt work either. Any suggestions? Idk if im close or way off. I have a hard time following registers =/

```
promptFirst:        .asciiz "Enter Your Starting Balance: \n"
promptSecond:       .asciiz "Enter the Interst Rate: \n"
promptThird:        .asciiz "Enter Your Target Balance \n"


promptNow:          .asciiz "\nYour Balance After A Iteration:\n"
.text
.globl main

main:   




     # Prints the first prompt  
     li $v0, 4               # syscall number 4 will print string whose address is in $a0       
     la $a0, promptFirst     # "load address" of the string
     syscall                 # actually print the string   

     # Reads in the first operand 
     li $v0, 5               # syscall number 5 will read an int
     syscall                 # actually read the int
     move $s0, $v0           # save result in $s0 for later


     # Prints the second prompt
     li $v0, 4               # syscall number 4 will print string whose address is in $a0   
     la $a0, promptSecond    # "load address" of the string
     syscall                 # actually print the string    

    # Reads in the second operand 
     li $v0, 5               # syscall number 5 will read an int
     syscall                 # actually read the int
     move $s1, $v0           # save result in $s1 for later

    # Prints the third prompt
     li $v0, 4               # syscall number 4 will print string whose address is in $a0   
     la $a0, promptThird    # "load address" of the string
     syscall                 # actually print the string    

    # Reads in the third operand 
     li $v0, 5               # syscall number 5 will read an int
     syscall                 # actually read the int
     move $s2, $v0           # save result in $s2 for later



jal LOOP

ENDLOOP:
j EXIT



LOOP:




    la  $a0, $s0    # load the address of the principal
    la  $a1, $s1    # load the address of the interest
    la  $a2, $s2    # load the address of the goal principal


    lwc1  $f2, ($a0)        # load the principal
    lwc1  $f4, ($a1)        # load the interest rate    
    lwc1  $f6  ($a2)

    mul.s $f12, $f4, $f2    # calculate the balance
    swc1  $f12, ($a0)

    li $v0, 4               # syscall number 4 will print      string whose address is in $a0   
    la $a0, promptNow       # "load address" of the string
    syscall                 # actually print the string
    li  $v0, 2              # system call #2    
    syscall

    addi $sp,$sp,-4     # push the current return address
    sw   $ra,($sp)      
    beq  $f12, $f6, LOOPRET

    beq $f12, $f6, ENDLOOP

    jal LOOP


LOOPRET:

    lw   $ra,($sp)      # pop the saved return address
    addi $sp,$sp,4      
    jr   $ra






EXIT:    
jr $ra
```

any suggestions would be nice. Theres a lot more to the problem that I need to do. But I need to get through this part first. I feel as if I have exhausted my brain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
la  $a0, $s0    # load the address of the principal
```

Does this even compile? The purpose of `la` is to [L]oad the [A]ddress of a label. You can't take the address of a register.

```
lwc1  $f2, ($a0)        # load the principal
```

Putting the incorrect value in `$a0` aside, `lwc1` does not perform any kind of integer-to-float conversion. So you wouldn't get a proper float by doing this.

What you probably should do is scrap the `la` / `lwc1` instructions and instead use something like:

```
mtc1 $s0,$f2     # move $s0 to floating point register $f2
cvt.s.w $f2,$f2  # convert the integer in $f2 to a float
# ..similarly for the rest of your values
```

Comment: Thanks, Im really new to assembly programming. Reason i was using the la instruction was because I was loading in a .float variable that I declared as PRINCIPAL which = 100. and I used( la $a0, PRINCIPAL).  I did that part as I was setting it up to get the recursion to work. I guess I assumed that the PRINCIPAL part was just a memory location that held 100. So my thought process was replace it with the memory location of the user imputed principal. But i guess I was quite wrong. =S so confusing. Its late here. I will check you solution tomorrow. I really appreciate you response. Thank you!

Comment: I tried you fix. I got passed that compile error. But now I get a compile error with the beq function calls. is there a floating point beq?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Im still plugging away at it. Haven't quite got it yet.